# How do I run a command via code?

Tags: vb6

Please help me run an external command from VB6:

I need to run the command

```
java  –jar  run.jar
```

Under the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\MY_SW_PROD\last\Java_sw
```

`run.jar` is inside the `java_sw` directory but my VB6 application is not.

I have the following code but it doesn't work because I am not inside the `java_sw` directory:

```
   Shell Environ("COMSPEC") & " /c  java  –jar  run.jar", vbNormalFocus
```

How do I change to the correct directory `C:\Program Files\MY_SW_PROD\last\Java_sw`, so that I will able to run the `run.jar` file?

Remark - ChDir isnt working on WIN XP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VB6 function `ChDir` to change the current working directory, prior to your `Shell`:

```
Dim currentDirectory as String

'Get the current working directory
currentDirectory = CurDir("C:")
'Change the current working directory
Call ChDir("C:\Program Files\MY_SW_PROD\last\Java_sw")
'Do you shell stuff here.

'Then set the current directory to the starting value
Call ChDir(currentDirectory)
```

(It's also good practice to set it back to the original value: use `CurDir` to store the current working directory).

If you want the command window to stay open, use `/K` instead of `/C` for `CMD.exe`.

Comment: please give me example because I not familiar with VB6

Comment: great - bdw - another question - what need to add in the syntax in order to stay the cmd window opened ( I run it and CMD window was closed after running ? )

Comment: I think you need to use the windows API to do that. (Google around and post another question if you can't find anything). It's pretty advanced stuff though.

Comment: I have problem - when I complie this code - I mean I do file --> make project.exe and run the project.exe then cmd not runing , what could be the problem ?

Comment: how it can be , why before the compile its ok and after something not work right with chDir .... ?

Comment: I have win XP and I think this not work on win xp - chDir isnt working on xp , please give me other idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: My *guess*, and it's only a guess, is that `Shell` in compiled code uses the "standalone" current directory settings whereas the debug version takes one from the debugger. One thing you could do is shell out to a batch file which i) changes the directory and ii) executes the java command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46220/discussion-between-eytan-and-bathsheba)